# Automorphisms of finite commutative algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, galois-theory

I am wondering about the automorphisms (or just morphisms) of a finite commutative algebra. We can just start with the simpliest example, say the $k$-algebra $k^n$ for a field $k$. On each factor the only k-algebra morphism is the identity. Each permutation of the components seems to give rise to an automorphism. My question is if we can describe all of them?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I read in the book "Algèbre et Théorie Galoisiennes (Douady)" (available only in french?) that the category of diagonalizable algebras (i.e isomorphic to some $k^n$) is anti-equivalent to the category of finite sets. This answers the basic case: the automorphisms are indeed the $n!$ permutations.

My motivation was that I wanted to know if perhaps we could view geometrically the elements of a Galois group (say of a Galois number field), by extending scalars to $\mathbb{C}$, as morphisms (of algebraic variety) of the affine line $\mathbb{C}$ that permute the roots of the minimal polynomial of a primitive element. If anyone can help?